# Dynamically add swing component to gui on click?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Purely theoretically when adding new components like that

```
JButton buttonAdd= new JButton("Add More");
        buttonAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  panel.add(new JComboBox<String>(data);
                  panel.add(new JTextField();
                }
        });
```

Is there way to **getSelectedIndex()** or **getText()** when u don't declare it in normal way?

Comment: *"Purely theoretically.."* Not much interested in theoretical questions. Practically speaking, why add components like that? What is the use-case that justifies it? As an aside it looks like the GUI would better need 1) An object that comprises a `String` for the text field and an `int` for the index of the data selected in the combo. 2) Use a `JList` with a custom renderer to display the objects formed in (1) 3) When the user selects a list item, show the details in s single text field and combo box placed outside the list. ..

Comment: .. But all that advice is dependent on assumptions as to what you are trying to achieve. For anything better than assumptions, explain how this GUI is supposed to work for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several ways to reach dynamicaly added components to swing tree:

**1st approach:**

```
panel.getComponent(n);
```

returns n'th component in the panel (Container). (n is the order, that component added to its parent (parent is `panel` here) ) (you need to know component's index) this way you can use `((JComboBox)panel.getComponent(3)).getSelectedIndex()`

**2nd approach**

directly add some listeners when dynamically adding your components;

```
JButton b1 = new JButton("add");
b1.addActionListener(e -> {  

    JComboBox<String> color = new JComboBox<String>();
    color.addActionListener(x -> { myFormBean.setColor(color.getSelectedItem();) });
    panel.add(color);

    JTextField name = new JTextField();
    name.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            myFormBean.setName(name.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            myFormBean.setName(name.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            myFormBean.setName(name.getText());
        }
    });
    panel.add(name);

    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();

});
```

this way you do not need to reach your dynamically added components.

**3rd approach** may be using a framework for data binding,

**4rd approach** ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add Swing components to the container this way. However you need to call `revalidate` on the panel, otherwise they may not appear instantly.

If you need to access these components after they are created, assign the value returned by constructor to the field of your object, declared inside your class. You cannot assign to the variable in the calling method as the constructors are called from the inner class.

Comment: @Michael [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/), [`Container#add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)), [`Component#revalidate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate())